# Prove: $d(a,b)=|f(a)-f(b)|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow $ $f$ is injective

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Prove: $d(a,b)=|f(a)-f(b)|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow $  $f$ is injective

$d(a,b)=0\iff a=b$ so we have:

$|f(a)-f(b)|=0\iff a=b$

But $|f(a)-f(b)|=0\Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)$

So $f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$

Is it correct? am I missing something?

Comment: yes; no,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(a)=f(b)$. Then $0=|f(a)-f(b)| = d(a,b)$ and so $a=b$ since $d$ is a metric.

Comment: Not significantly different than what the OP did so far as I can tell.

Comment: @fleablood I'd say it's much better written. The OP includes if and only if's rather than only the relevant implications.

Comment: Yes, it is better written but the OP was asking if his/her proof was correct.  This post doesn't address that and implies, by proving the whole thing from scratch, that it wasn't.  Also it doesn't matter if it was better written.  It is still the same proof.

Comment: @fleablood yes, definitely agree. it should be a comment rather than an answer. I was just responding to your first comment. though I would say it's more than just "better written"; it eliminates some unnecessary content.